# Store loop result for each iteration as separate vectors

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have all-characters matrix with 13 row and 28 columns (my_matrix):

```
    N   N  ...  S  N
    N   S  ...  F  N
    N   S  ...  Z  NA
    NA  S  ...  F  NA
    .. ..  ...  .. ..
    NA NA  ...  N  NA
```

What I want to do is

1. Delete all NA(s)
2. Delete all column that has at least one of these characters: "Z", 
   "B", "E", "V", "D", "VS", "VZ"

And store them as separate vectors, looked like this way (or by row, either way is okay):

```
my_vector1 = N N N
my_vector2 = N S S S ...etc.
```

What I have done is to write a loop looks like this:

```
forbidden_letter <- c("Z", "B", "E", "V", "D", "VS", "VZ")
for(i in 1:28) { 
  if(!any(forbidden_letter %in% my_matrix[,i]==TRUE)){   
temp_my_vector <- matrix(my_matrix[,i], byrow = TRUE)
my_vector <- matrix(temp_my_vector[!temp_my_vector %in% NA], byrow= TRUE)
print(my_vector)}
}
my_vector
```

With this piece of code, I only get the last iteration's of my_vector

How do I save each iterations into separate vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider some data:

```
(dat <- cbind(c("N", "N", "N", NA, NA), c("N", "S", "S", "S", NA), c("S", "F", "Z", "F", "N"), c("N", "N", NA, NA, NA)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "N"  "N"  "S"  "N" 
# [2,] "N"  "S"  "F"  "N" 
# [3,] "N"  "S"  "Z"  NA  
# [4,] NA   "S"  "F"  NA  
# [5,] NA   NA   "N"  NA  
forbidden_letter <- c("Z", "B", "E", "V", "D", "VS", "VZ")
```

You can process each column separately with `apply`:

```
(vectors <- apply(dat, 2, function(x) if (any(x %in% forbidden_letter)) NULL else x[!is.na(x)]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "N" "N" "N"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "N" "S" "S" "S"
# 
# [[3]]
# NULL
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "N" "N"
```

You could then get the vector for each column with:

```
vectors[[1]]
# [1] "N" "N" "N"
vectors[[4]]
# [1] "N" "N"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to filter your matrix based on some conditions.

If you have a matrix `my_matrix`, you can first filter columns with forbidden letters:

```
for(col in names(my_matrix)) {
    if (any(my_matrix[, col] %in% forbidden_letter)) {
        my_matrix[, col] <- NULL
    }
}
```

This will delete columns with forbidden letters.

Now, you can access any column via

```
my_matrix[, col_name]
```

or

```
my_matrix[, col_index]
```

And the result is already a vector, as you want. You don't need to store each column in another variable as you intended. The `matrix` object already does that for you.

Finally, to remove the `NA` values, you can simply do `na.omit` after filtering. For example,

```
print(na.omit(my_matrix[, 3]))
```

will print out only non-NA values of your third column. The logic can be extended to any column.